# rtabmap stereo with original (mono) Bumblebee

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap, bumblebee, stereo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to set up an original Bumblebee stereo camera with rtabmap. Currently, the issue that I am running into is that stereo_odometry is crashing without giving a discernible error message.

```
[FATAL] (2015-06-02 12:04:18.939) SensorData.cpp:92::SensorData() Condition (!depthOrRightImage.empty() && _fx>0.0f && _fyOrBaseline>0.0f && _cx>=0.0f && _cy>=0.0f) not met!

*******
FATAL message occurred! Application will now exit.

*******
[stereo_odometry-5] process has died [pid 6850, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/rtabmap_ros/stereo_odometry left/image_rect:=/stereo_camera/left/image_rect right/image_rect:=/stereo_camera/right/image_rect left/camera_info:=/stereo_camera/left/camera_info right/camera_info:=/stereo_camera/right/camera_info odom:=/odometry __name:=stereo_odometry __log:=/home/rockie/.ros/log/3f5c6f20-093f-11e5-a60c-4cbb583a0a1c/stereo_odometry-5.log].
log file: /home/rockie/.ros/log/3f5c6f20-093f-11e5-a60c-4cbb583a0a1c/stereo_odometry-5*.log
```

Relevant parts of my launch file look like:

Camera:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="camera1394stereo" type="camera1394stereo_node" name="camera1394stereo_node" output="screen" >
    <param name="video_mode" value="1024x768_mono16" />
    <param name="format7_color_coding" value="raw16" />
    <param name="bayer_pattern" value="" />
    <param name="bayer_method" value="" />
    <param name="stereo_method" value="Interlaced" />
    <param name="camera_info_url_left" value="file://$(find stereo_slam)/config/cal_left.yaml" />
    <param name="camera_info_url_right" value="file://$(find stereo_slam)/config/cal_right.yaml" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

Rectification:

```
 <!-- Run the ROS package stereo_image_proc for image rectification -->
  <group ns="/stereo_camera" >
    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="stereo_nodelet"  args="manager"/>
  
    <node pkg="stereo_image_proc" type="stereo_image_proc" name="stereo_image_proc">
      <param name="disparity_range" value="128"/>
    </node>
  </group>
```

Transform:

```
  <arg name="pi/2" value="1.5707963267948966" />
  <arg name="optical_rotate" value="0 0 0 -$(arg pi/2) 0 -$(arg pi/2)" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="camera_base_link"
    args="$(arg optical_rotate) base_link stereo_camera 100" />
```

Odometry:

```
   <node pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="stereo_odometry" name="stereo_odometry" output="screen" >
      <remap from="left/image_rect"       to="/stereo_camera/left/image_rect"/>
      <remap from="right/image_rect"      to="/stereo_camera/right/image_rect"/>
      <remap from="left/camera_info"      to="/stereo_camera/left/camera_info"/>
      <remap from="right/camera_info"     to="/stereo_camera/right/camera_info"/>
      <remap from="odom"                  to="/odometry"/>

      <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="base_link"/>
      <param name="odom_frame_id" type="string" value="odom"/>
    
      <param name="Odom/InlierDistance" type="string" value="0.1"/>
      <param name="Odom/MinInliers" type="string" value="10"/>
      <param name="Odom/RoiRatios" type="string" value="0.03 0.03 0.04 0.04"/>
      <param name="Odom/MaxDepth" type="string" value="10"/>
      <param name="OdomBow/NNDR" type="string" value="0.8"/>
      
      <param name="GFTT/MaxCorners" type="string" value="500"/>
      <param name="GFTT/MinDistance" type="string" value="5"/>
  
      <param name="Odom/FillInfoData" type="string" value="true"/>
   </node>
```

Any ideas what my issue could be?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210424/rtabmap-stereo-with-original-(mono)-bumblebee/) by [micah.corah](https://answers.ros.org/users/19437/micah.corah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2015-06-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue was that the left and right cameras were switched. Remapping each side in camera1394stereo fixed the problem. Rtab-map in Indigo warns that the baseline is negative which tipped me off.

---

Originally posted by [micah.corah](https://answers.ros.org/users/19437/micah.corah/) with karma: 66 on 2015-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0